# Netsh firewall: allow a port just for a single interface

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, netsh

In Win7 with netsh I would like to allow a listening port only on a single interface and block it on all the other interfaces.

With the GUI this is possible using the "Protected Network Connections->Customize" in the snap-in properties.

[image]
Source: [windowsitpro.com/](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/q-how-can-i-disable-or-enable-windows-firewall-specific-network-connection)

In PowerShell too, the following command is available:

```
Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name Private -DisabledInterfaceAliases 'Connection Name'
```

Via COM it is possible to access the [Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property for a rule via the  `INetFwRule` interface.

So what about netsh?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firewalling VirtualBox: restrict host inbound connections to guests only](http://superuser.com/questions/816057/firewalling-virtualbox-restrict-host-inbound-connections-to-guests-only)

Comment: @Kenster Ok, redacted with more context